# Predict the next four numbers in a series of numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series

List the next four numbers in this sequence:

1,4,9,1,6,2,5,3,6,4,9,6,4,8,1

What is the pattern?

Comment: $1,0,0,1$ probably. But any continuation could be justified.

Comment: Write out the squares of integers, then slice them up.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81...

This sequence is related to the Champernowne constant.